# How to restrict user to verify the mobile by OTP after 4 hours of OTPgeneration

Tags: java, spring-boot, time, clickatell

> I have created Api for Verify mobile and i want to put some logic so
>   that i can restrict the user who try to verify otp after 4 hours. I
>   have created two Apis **first one send otp to user and the input
>   parameter is mobile number.**
>   **Second API verify that mobile number by comparing the otp inserted by user and that stored in database during first API**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class MobileController2 {


    private String To = null;
    OtpGenerator otp = new OtpGenerator();
    @Autowired
    private MobileRepository mobileRepository;
    Sms sms = new Sms();
    Date date = new Date();
    Timestamp timestamp1 = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");


    @PostMapping(value = "/mobile", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Mobile> createMobile(@RequestBody Mobile mobile) {
        int hashcode = otp.RandomOtp();
        this.To = mobile.getMob();
        String Message = hashcode + " is your Pharmerz verification code ";

        if (mobileRepository.findByUserid(mobile.getUserid()) != null) {
            Mobile mobileprevious = mobileRepository.findByUserid(mobile.getUserid());
            mobileprevious.setMob(mobile.getMob());
            mobileprevious.setHASHCODE("" + hashcode);
            mobileprevious.setUpdated(mobile.getUpdated());
            mobileprevious.setVERIFIED(0);
            mobileRepository.save(mobileprevious);
            sms.sms_generation(To, Message);
            return new ResponseEntity<Mobile>(mobileprevious, HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            mobile.setHASHCODE("" + hashcode);
            mobile.setVERIFIED(0);
            mobileRepository.save(mobile);

            sms.sms_generation(To, Message);
            return new ResponseEntity<Mobile>(mobile, HttpStatus.OK);

        }
    }



    @PostMapping(value = "/verifymobile", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Mobile> verifyMobile(@RequestBody Mobile mobile) {

        String userid = mobile.getUserid();
        String userotp = mobile.getHASHCODE();
        Mobile mobileobject = mobileRepository.findByUserid(userid);
        if (mobileobject.getHASHCODE().equals(userotp)) {
            System.out.println("Matched");
            mobileobject.setHASHCODE("");
            mobileobject.setVERIFIED(1);

            mobileRepository.save(mobileobject);
            String Acknowledge = "Thank you for verifying on Pharmerz";
            sms.sms_generation(To, Acknowledge);

            return new ResponseEntity<Mobile>(mobileobject, HttpStatus.OK);

        } else {
            System.out.println("Miss matched");
            return new ResponseEntity<Mobile>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Any feedback on my answer? I know you probably hoped for me; but I am pretty sure: nothing else will be showing up here ...

Comment: I have solved this issue by checking the difference for zone time.

Comment: I take that as: my answer was helpful, but didn't really solve your problem?

Comment: No your answer was really appriciated it gave me the path for my work

Comment: Glad to hear that ... but I agree, not every answer must lead to an *accept* though ;-)

Comment: Can you help me out by giving me suggestion . How can i again post questions on stack overflow at it has been banned on there.

Comment: Sorry. When you got banned from asking, that for sure happened for a certain reasons. And that doesn't happen out of the blue. You should have received warnings prior to that happening. And shouldnt such bans be temporarily? In that sense: you have to wait. If you think that you got banned for "invalid" reasons, you can **always** flag one of your questions for moderator attention and explain your problem. But please understand that *only* moderators can help with such things; and that such bans are in fact a result of you doing things the wrong way, and probably not listening to feedback.

Answer (score 4):

Giving you a non-answer here: learn how to write helpful log messages and how to make use of tools such as [debuggers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdb.html) or [profilers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/profiler.html).

Meaning: *nobody* can debug such a problem from remote. There could be all kinds of root causes giving you this behavior.

*You* have to step back and

- understand that putting the string "error log" into your error log doesn't help *anything*.
- understand that printing to the console ... is also not a reliable way to attain "logs" of your code. Especially when having the same message "Wrong or Old Otp" in three different places. That's called *code duplication* and per se a *bad practice*!
- learn to use tools that give you insights about the *health* of your application.

In other words: the *primary goal* of *logging* information within your application is to **enable** you to debug problems after they took place. Exactly to support you in situations such as this.